# How to make the Http port change permanent in Oracle 10g xe?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I  did the following:-

```
SQL> Exec DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(7070);     

procedure successfully completed
```

However now each time i have to manually change the port number on URL to 7070,
 by default it is set to

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8080/htmldb".
```

How to make it go to 7070 by default?

Comment: Where is it set to that? Where are you getting the URL from before you have to change it?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have Tomcat set to :8080 and i changed Oracle to :7070.However since :8080 is default HTTP Port, hence when I go to Database Home page it takes :8080, which i then manually set to :7070 in URL bar. I want it to take :7070 automatically since I have already made the change. - Thanks.

Comment: But how do you 'go to Database Home page' - is that a link from somewhere else, a bookmark, a shortcut, something else?

Comment: @AlexPoole                                                       Oracle Database 10g Express Edition --> Go To Database Home Page

Comment: ok, I got it...go to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server Open Database_homepage in Notepad and change the port to 7070(Assuming you want it to be 8080) and save. Log out from the windows account and log back in. Done.. :-)